# Writing row from structured numpy array with varying delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have some data stored in a structured numpy array that I would like to write to a file. Because I'm generating some code to match an existing output format that exported a more visually pleasant table I need to output this data with a varying whitespace delimiter.

Using a basic example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((2,),dtype=('i4,f4,a10'))
x[:] = [(1,2.,'Hello'),(2,3.,'World')]
```

With a desired output of:

```
1 2.00    Hello
2 3.00    World
```

Now, I know I could do this:

```
for row in x:
    print('%i %.2f    %s' % (row[0], row[1], row[2]))
```

Which works fine but it seems overly verbose if you have a lot of columns. Right now there are 8 in my output.

I'm new to Python (coming from MATLAB), is there a more generic statement that I could use to 'roll up' all of the columns? I was thinking something along the lines of `print('%i %.2f    %s' % val for val in row)` but this just prints 2 generators. When I ran into a generator while using `re.split` I could use `list()` to get my desired output, but I don't think using something similar with, say, `str()` for this case would do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you elaborate what the `varying whitespace delimiter` looks like? Which rules does the number of whitespaces follow?

Comment: @cel There is no rule, it's however I specify it in the format string

Comment: If the number of whitespaces is completely arbitrary and does not follow any pattern, you probably cannot do better than specifying the format string manually. If you switch to `string.format` you can at least combine formatting with tuple unpacking: `'{} {:.2f}    {}'.format(*rows)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap `row` in a `tuple`, you don't have to list all the elements.  `%` formats take a `tuple`.  `row` may display as a `tuple` but it is actually a `numpy.void`.

```
for row in x:
    print('%i %.2f   %s'%tuple(row))
```

Printing or writing rows in a loop like this is perfectly normal Python.

Class `__str__` methods are often written like:

```
astr=['a header line']
for row in x:
    astr.append('%i %.2f   %s'%tuple(row))
astr='\n'.join(astr)
```

producing a string of joined lines.

A comprehension equivalent could be:

```
'\n'.join('%i %.2f   %s'%tuple(row) for row in x)
```

Since you are using Python3, you could also use the `.format` approach, but I suspect the `%` style is closer to what you are using in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for! Appreciate the background info too :)

Answer (score 1):

**First:**
 Regarding your implicit question with the generators;
 you can "stringify" a generator for example with `str.join`:

```
>>> gen = (i.upper() for i in "teststring")
>>> print(''.join(gen))
TESTSTRING
```

**Second:**
 To the actual question: It is a little bit more generic, than your approach, but it is still not really satisfying.

```
formats = [
    ("{}", 1),      # format and number of spaces for row[0]
    ("{.2f}", 4),   # the same for row[1]
    ("{}", 0)       # and row[2]
]
for row in x:
    lst = [f.format(d) + (" "*s) for (f, s, d) in zip(formats, row)]
    print(*lst, sep='')
```

It just provides a better overview over each format.

Comment: Thanks for the info! This works but the other answer is what I was looking for.